# Find and Replace blank values with the value from the cell above

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 500,000 cells of data in 1 column in excel. The data looks like:

Column F:

> 1528
>   1660
>   N/A
>   1531
>   1531
>   N/A
>   N/A

is there any way I can replace all N/A' with the value from the cell above?

If I did it row by row it would take me a year. So thank you in advance if you are able to save me from wasting a year of my life by doing this manually.

Comment: You can take a look at this and modify for "N/A": http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/enter-data-into-many-cells-at-once/

Comment: Marked as a duplicate as it is the same question once the *N/A* are replaced with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1 - you could use a formula in the column next to it.

The formula in cell G2 would be 
=IF(F2="N/A",F1,F2)
copy and paste this down into all column G cells.  You will notice that the formula changes after it is copied.

Now highlight the G column and COPY.

Then highlight the F column, and right click one the selection and choose PasteSpecial from the popup then choose Values only and OK which will copy the value calculated in G over those that were in in F.

Keep a backup before you do it!

OPTION 2 - You can do it using code like this:

```
Public Sub FixData()

Dim acell As Range

For Each acell In ActiveSheet.Columns("F").Cells
    If acell.Value = "N/A" And acell.Row <> 1 Then
        acell.Select
        acell.Value = acell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next acell

End Sub
```

Ok?

Comment: I'm downvoting because that many `SELECT`s will be slow, and are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Harvey French - you saved 1 year of my life, for that I am extremely grateful. Seriously though thank you!!!

Comment: Doug.  The method you suggested won't work.  How would you do it.   Then vote me up if it's no better than mine.  PS>  The select is clearly in there for easy testing - it can be taken out easily by anyone who understands the code.

Comment: @HarveyFrench Replace all the N/A with blanks, then use Doug's approach. If you know the `Select` is redundant then why not remove it? :)

Comment: Actually, replace blanks with "xxxzzzaaa", replace n/a with blanks, then Dougs approach works,  then replace "xxxzzzaaa" with blanks.  I think adding the column is simpler and a more visible approach which let's you see what's going to happen. It also worked.

Comment: @HarveyFrench, FYI, if you put an @ before a username they'll be notified that you addressed a comment to them.